# i want to resize an image but it shows an error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to program a code that accepts an image,rescales it to a smaller values,uses border detection and gives out an ASCII art.

But the problem arises with the part where im unable to retrieve the rescaled imagge.

here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot
# load image as pixel array
image = image.imread(r'C:\Users\lavni\OneDrive\Desktop\asci.png')
# summarize shape of the pixel array
print(image.dtype)
print(image.shape)
image=image.resize((52,int((image.shape[1]*52)/image.shape[0])))
# display the array of pixels as an image
pyplot.imshow(image)
pyplot.show()
```

and i get the error:

```
(648, 1152, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lavni/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/ASCII.py", line 11, in <module>
    pyplot.imshow(image)
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2645, in imshow
    __ret = gca().imshow(
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1565, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 358, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 358, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5626, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 693, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use openCV library

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Code:

```
import cv2
img2 = cv2.imread(filename)
resized = cv2.resize(img2, dsize=(28,28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Comment: how do i install the library? pip install cv2 doesnt work

Comment: pip install opencv-python